# DocuSign API - Envelope Sharing Between Account Users

Tags: docusignapi

An example to my issue is I just created a new user in DocuSign and need to assign several other existing users to share this user's envelopes through the eSignature REST API. I am aware there is a way to do this through the GUI, but is there an equivalent to adding users through "Share envelopes with user" and "Share user's envelopes" through the API?

Guide to add sharing through GUI: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-share-envelopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, through the UpdateSharedAccess method, which is documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Accounts/Accounts/updateSharedAccess

For example, a `PUT` call to `{{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/shared_access?preserve_existing_shared_access=true` with the following body:

```
{
    "sharedAccess": [{
        "user": {
            "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        },
        "envelopes": [{
            "user": {
                "userId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
            },
            "shared": "shared_to"
        }]
    }]
}
```

will allow the 0000 user to view the 1111 user's documents

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!