# Is it possible to impersonate organization users using Authorization Code grant?

Tags: docusignapi

Here is what I am expecting:

- Organization Org1 has users U1, U2, U3 and U4.
- Now, U1 logged to application, created an envelope and wanted to send it to U2 as draft(U2 will have that in his draft) for review/edit.
- Once U2 correct an envelope he will send it to signers U3 and U4 for signing.

Here what I tried in my case:

- U1 logged into application, provided consent and sent envelope with envelope status as 'created'('created' - so that it would be in intended user's draft folder. In this case U2) then an envelope going into draft of U1 as he has provided consent rather that draft of user U2.
- When I set envelope status as 'sent' then envelope goes into inbox of U2 rather than in draft of U2

Is it possible to impersonate organization users using Authorization Code grant, so that no need of intended user consent to send envelope in his draft?

Answer (score 1):

So, first, few clarifications for you:

- You say "org" you mean account. DocuSign does have organizations which include more than one account. Account is a unit an organization may use, which is what you mean in Org1 I think.
- Your scenario can be done with Auth Code Grant or JWT, this is independent of your use case.

What you need is to share the envelopes between the users. Here is an answer about how to do that with the eSign REST API:

[DocuSign API - Envelope Sharing Between Account Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617614/docusign-api-envelope-sharing-between-account-users)

```
PUT call to {{vx}}/accounts/{{accountid}}/shared_access?
{
    "sharedAccess": [{
        "user": {
            "userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        },
        "envelopes": [{
            "user": {
                "userId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
            },
            "shared": "shared_to"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: But in that case I need intended user's userId, which is extra effort. And that would be done only after sending envelope.

Comment: not sure I understand the concern. Yes, you need to who are U1 ,U2, U3 and U4 in your example and find their IDs. You can cache this as this information doesn't change.

Comment: and yes, you need to do that after the envelope is created, but not necessary after it is sent. As long as you have the envelopeID - you can share it.